# Are anonymous string literals inefficient?

Tags: c, string

Consider the following code:

```
bool isFoo(const char* bar) {
    return !strcmp(bar, "some_long_complicated_name");
}
```

Here, the string literal `"some_long_complicated_name"` is immediately passed to `strcmp`. Does this mean that everytime `isFoo` is called, accordingly many bytes of this string literal is allocated on that stack frame? If that was the case, wouldn't this:

```
const char FOO_NAME[] = "some_long_complicated_name";
bool isFoo(const char* bar) {
    return !strcmp(bar, FOO_NAME);
}
```

be more efficient?

Comment: These are almost equivalent in terms of memory use.

Comment: @mvp why almost and not precisely?

Comment: They are placed in memory and reused each time because they are const.

Comment: *why almost and not precisely?* The only differences are (1) in the second version the name `FOO_NAME` will be visible in the symbol table and (2) in the first version, under some (typically older) compilers, the array will not be qualified as `const`. But other than that, yes, the implementation of a string literal is as a nameless, static array of characters. (And, yes, the run-time memory usage is probably identical.)

Comment: The array, as the second parameter to `strcmp()` will be passed to the function as the address of the first byte of the array,  The actual array will be generated at compile time (and linked into readonly memory)  So, in both cases, all `strcmp()` will be passed is a memory pointer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not inefficient. They are usually placed in the read-only memory part of your compiled binary, as their size is known at compile time and they can't be modified during runtime.

The expensive parts of strings (in terms of runtime performance) is the memory allocation. In both versions of `isFoo`, there is no memory allocation taking place, so I'd assume that it's quite hard to measure a performance difference between the two. `FOO_NAME` technically occupies some bytes somewhere, but is likely to be optimized away by the compiler.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/tTJqO6) are both versions on compiler explorer. The assembly with `-O3` is not identical, but to be honest, I am not able to further exploit these results.

Comment: @super I don't think so. Note that in the long version, it does not call at all `strcmp`. The compiler understood the string comparison, and completely replaced the call to `strcmp` with ASM instructions (`cmpsb` and a loop with `repz`); while in the short version, since the compiler cannot infer the string comparison as easily, it has to call `strcmp` which, despite being a really optimised function, is *probably* slower than the two asm functions of the other version.

Comment: Good point. Interestingly, with `clang -O3`, both versions are identical.

Answer (score 2):

Constant strings do not get allocated, they are merely stored within the compiled binary and accessed via pointer. So no, there is no difference in speed between either approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolute no change in the compiled file. It will result in the exact same binary!

If you compile both versions in a single executable like this:

```
bool isFoo(const char* bar) {
    return !strcmp(bar, "some_long_complicated_name");
}   

const char FOO_NAME[] = "some_long_complicated_name";
bool isFoo2(const char* bar) {
    return !strcmp(bar, FOO_NAME);
}   

int main()
{
    isFoo( "nnn" );
    isFoo2( "nnn" );
}
```

You can investigate the binary:

```
0000000000401156 <isFoo(char const*)>:
  401156:   55                      push   %rbp
  401157:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40115a:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  40115e:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  401162:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  401166:   be c0 20 40 00          mov    $0x4020c0,%esi
  40116b:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40116e:   e8 cd fe ff ff          callq  401040 <strcmp@plt>
  401173:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  401175:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al 
  401178:   c9                      leaveq 
  401179:   c3                      retq   

000000000040117a <isFoo2(char const*)>:
  40117a:   55                      push   %rbp
  40117b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40117e:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  401182:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  401186:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  40118a:   be e0 20 40 00          mov    $0x4020e0,%esi
  40118f:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  401192:   e8 a9 fe ff ff          callq  401040 <strcmp@plt>
  401197:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  401199:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al 
  40119c:   c9                      leaveq 
  40119d:   c3                      retq
```

and here the strings are located:

```
4020c0 736f6d65 5f6c6f6e 675f636f 6d706c69  some_long_compli
4020d0 63617465 645f6e61 6d650000 00000000  cated_name......
4020e0 736f6d65 5f6c6f6e 675f636f 6d706c69  some_long_compli
4020f0 63617465 645f6e61 6d65006e 6e6e00    cated_name.nnn.
```

You also see the "nnn" string here!

The output was generated with:

> objdump -s -S go | c++filt > x

Attention: You have to compile with `-O0` as otherwise the compiler is smart enough to do all the stuff already in compile time. If I use `-O2` none of the strings can be seen anymore and all call results are present already in the binary. Good to see how much a compiler can do in compile time!

So exactly NO difference, exactly the same binary code. But with standard optimization, no code generated for string compare, already done in compile time!

I modified main to see that the result of the comparison is used somewhere with:

```
    int main()
    {   
        volatile bool x;
        x = isFoo( "nnn" );
        x = isFoo2( "nnn" );
    }
```

The resulting binary:

```
0000000000401060 <main>:
    }

    int main()
    {
        volatile bool x;
        x = isFoo( "nnn" );
  401060:   c6 44 24 ff 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1(%rsp)
        x = isFoo2( "nnn" );
    }
  401065:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
        x = isFoo2( "nnn" );
  401067:   c6 44 24 ff 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1(%rsp)
    }
  40106c:   c3                      retq
```

As you can see, the result of the comparison is already present in the compiled code. No string is compared anymore in runtime.

For all questions regarding speed and memory usage: Measure! As you can see in the example, the results are different to most assumptions we see in other answers. If speed or memory footprint is really important: Take a look on the compiler generated results. Mostly it is much more perfect as you think!